# Mocking a service thats provided in a component controller in a unit test

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, angularjs-service

This is the error I'm seeing when trying to run my unit test ..

```
Expected undefined to be defined.
TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$rootScope.$digest')

Module 'ThirdPartyModule' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Any ideas how to mock the `testService` so that I can still compile my component?

test.component.spec.ts

```
import { TestModule } from '../index';

describe('Component: testComponent', () => {

  let $rootScope: angular.IScope;
  let element: angular.IAugmentedJQuery;

  beforeEach(() => {
    angular.mock.module('ui.router');
    angular.mock.module(TestModule.name);
  });

  beforeEach(inject((
    _$rootScope_: angular.IScope,
    $compile: angular.ICompileService,
    _$state_: angular.ui.IStateService) => {
    $rootScope = _$rootScope_;
    element = angular.element('<test></test>');
    element = $compile(element)($rootScope);
  }));

  it('should verify component compiled and rendered template', () => {
    expect(element).toBeDefined();
    $rootScope.$digest();
    let link = element.find('a');
    expect(link.text()).toContain('Click this link!');
  });
});
```

test.module.ts

```
import { TestComponent } from './test';

export let TestModule: ng.IModule = angular.module(
  'test', // my module name
  ['ui.router', 'ThirdPartyModule']) // dependencies, ThirdPartyModule contains testService
  .component('test', new TestComponent());
```

test.component.ts

```
import { TestComponentController } from './test.component.controller';

export class TestComponent implements ng.IComponentOptions {
  public template: string = '<a ng-if="ctrl.serviceReturned">Click this link!</a>';
  public controller: Function = TestComponentController;
  public controllerAs: string = 'ctrl';

  constructor() {}
}
```

test.component.controller.ts

```
export class TestComponentController {

  public serviceReturned: boolean = false;

  constructor(private testService: any) {
    if (this.testService.isDone()) {
      this.serviceReturned = true;
    }
  }
}

TestComponentController.$inject = ['testService'];
```

Comment: An error happens during `inject` that causes $rootScope and element to be undefined and it's not shown here. It's not possible to say what's wrong without knowing the error. if it's suppressed, catch it with try...catch in beforeEach.

Comment: heres the error, i updated question .. `Module 'ThirdPartyModule' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.`

Comment: I guess the error explains it all. The module was not loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't you need to add 'ThirdPartyModule' in an angular.mock.module?